# Tridion Sites User Documentation Survey

Tags: discussion

Dear Tridion Sites user,

The Tridion Sites technical writing team would be grateful for 10 minutes from your day to help us improve our user documentation by doing a survey. You can click the link below or scan the QR code.

[This survey is strictly confidential and closes on Friday August 6th.](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/TridionDoc2021)

[image: QR code for survey]